# Get icon from label and load it to imagebutton?

Tags: android, spinner, imagebutton

I've got a spinner and an imagebutton. 
The spinner is loaded with labels that i get from a package manager. 
The imagebutton should update its drawable when the user chooses a new label.

Here is my code so far:

```
    @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Drawable icon = (Drawable) (parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
    ImageButton image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
    image.setImageDrawable(icon.loadIcon(pm));

}
```

At "loadIcon" there is the error message:

**The method loadIcon(PackageManager) is undefined for the type Drawable**

Any hints or ideas how I can get this working?

Comment: this `image.setImageDrawable(icon.loadIcon(pm));` should be `image.setImageDrawable(icon);` because you have already taken drawbles from package manager

Comment: Are the labels from different apps?

Comment: Yes, they are from different apps, I load them to spinner with an ArrayList<String>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recode like this. It will work

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Drawable icon = (Drawable) (parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
ImageButton image = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
image.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
```

Comment: Sorry, code seems to be clean in Eclipse but crashes on the device...

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.Drawable**

Comment: @berkley change ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<drawable>